# How do I strengthen the ability to open a door knob?

Tags: exercise, hands

Is there a way to strengthen the hand palm twist motion? A 50 years old is training using kettlebells as well as hand barbells daily. However, he has difficulties in twist motion of the hand palm against door knob. Is there a way to improve it and strength it so he will find it easier to twist door knob resistance?

Comment: Have you tried doing hand circles in rice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Forearm rotation exercises](https://exrx.net/Articulations/Forearm) and grip strength exercises**

The forearm rotation exercises can be performed either with a plate-loadable dumbbell with plates on one side only (as pictured above), or just by gripping a fixed dumbbell with the hand shifted as far to one side of the handle as is possible (so that the thumb is pressing up against the end) and then repeating on the other side (so that they pinky finger is pressing up against the other end).

Stress balls make a good grip strength exerciser for someone whose grip strength is currently at a level where they are having difficulty turning door knobs.